# scrollable table with fixed header

Tags: javascript, html, css

My table having 5 columns and several rows,the tbody is scrollable,
my problem is when I use colspan to combine 5 column in first thead row the entire table alignment is getting changed,
how can I use that
if the colspan is not in thead working fine
i need to use colspan to combine,
for this I am getting error

my code is

```js
var $table = $('table.scroll'),
$bodyCells = $table.find('tbody tr:first').children(),
colWidth;

//Adjust the width of thead cells when window resizes
$(window).resize(function() {
// Get the tbody columns width array
colWidth = $bodyCells.map(function() {
    return $(this).width();
}).get();

// Set the width of thead columns
$table.find('thead tr').children().each(function(i, v) {
    $(v).width(colWidth[i]);
});    
}).resize(); // Trigger resize handler
```

```css
wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
body {
    background-color:#a6e2ff;
}
.scroll table{
    margin: 5% auto auto auto;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: inherit;
    border-spacing: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: 2px solid #B7B7B7;
}
.scroll tbody tr:hover {
    background-color: #CECECE;
}
.scroll  td:hover {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
.scroll thead {
    background: #335599;background:linear-gradient(to bottom left,#335599,#335599);
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
 height:auto;
}
.scroll td, .scroll th {
    border: 1px solid #B7B7B7;
}
.scroll tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #f2f2f2}
.scroll td{
    padding: 8px;
}
.scroll th{
    padding: 8px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
display: none;
}
table.scroll tbody,table.scroll thead {
    display: block;
}
thead tr th { 
    height: 30px;
    line-height: auto;
}
table.scroll tbody {
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper scroll">
<table class="scroll">
    <thead><tr><th colspan="5" style="width: 240mm;">Head 2</th></tr></thead>
    <thead><tr><th style="width: 100mm;">Head 1</th><th style="width: 50mm;">Head 2</th><th style="width: 30mm;">Head 3</th><th style="width: 30mm;">Head 4</th><th style="width: 30mm;">Head 5</th></tr></thead>
    <thead><tr><th style="width: 100mm;">Head 1</th><th style="width: 50mm;">Head 2</th><th style="width: 30mm;">Head 3</th><th style="width: 30mm;">Head 4</th><th style="width: 30mm;">Head 5</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td style="width: 100mm;">Content 1</td><td style="width: 50mm;">Content 2</td><td style="width: 30mm;">Content 3</td><td style="width: 30mm;">Content 4</td><td style="width: 30mm;">Content 5</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Content 1</td><td>Content 2</td><td>Content 3</td><td>Content 4</td><td>Content 5</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Content 1</td><td>Content 2</td><td>Content 3</td><td>Content 4</td><td>Content 5</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Content 1</td><td>Content 2</td><td>Content 3</td><td>Content 4</td><td>Content 5</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Content 1</td><td>Content 2</td><td>Content 3</td><td>Content 4</td><td>Content 5</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Content 1</td><td>Content 2</td><td>Content 3</td><td>Content 4</td><td>Content 5</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Content 1</td><td>Content 2</td><td>Content 3</td><td>Content 4</td><td>Content 5</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Content 1</td><td>Content 2</td><td>Content 3</td><td>Content 4</td><td>Content 5</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Content 1</td><td>Content 2</td><td>Content 3</td><td>Content 4</td><td>Content 5</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Content 1</td><td>Content 2</td><td>Content 3</td><td>Content 4</td><td>Content 5</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Content 1</td><td>Content 2</td><td>Content 3</td><td>Content 4</td><td>Content 5</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Content 1</td><td>Content 2</td><td>Content 3</td><td>Content 4</td><td>Content 5</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Content 1</td><td>Content 2</td><td>Content 3</td><td>Content 4</td><td>Content 5</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Content 1</td><td>Content 2</td><td>Content 3</td><td>Content 4</td><td>Content 5</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Content 1</td><td>Content 2</td><td>Content 3</td><td>Content 4</td><td>Content 5</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table></div>
```

Comment: Please add your code here.

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: The alignment on tables will always focus on the first `<thead>` and/or `<tr><th>` found. Consider adding some empty `<th>` tags to fill up the empty space.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible to create header fixed with sorting by using `javascript`. if possible a lots of code you need to write so i preferred you can use any `javascript framework` which will easy to configure and implement. i have used `https://datatables.net/` in n no of project

working example as below with codes :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var dataSet = [
    ["Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", "5421", "2011/04/25", "$320,800"],
    ["Garrett Winters", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "8422", "2011/07/25", "$170,750"],
    ["Ashton Cox", "Junior Technical Author", "San Francisco", "1562", "2009/01/12", "$86,000"],
    ["Cedric Kelly", "Senior Javascript Developer", "Edinburgh", "6224", "2012/03/29", "$433,060"],
    ["Airi Satou", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "5407", "2008/11/28", "$162,700"],
    ["Brielle Williamson", "Integration Specialist", "New York", "4804", "2012/12/02", "$372,000"],
    ["Herrod Chandler", "Sales Assistant", "San Francisco", "9608", "2012/08/06", "$137,500"],
    ["Rhona Davidson", "Integration Specialist", "Tokyo", "6200", "2010/10/14", "$327,900"],
    ["Colleen Hurst", "Javascript Developer", "San Francisco", "2360", "2009/09/15", "$205,500"],
    ["Sonya Frost", "Software Engineer", "Edinburgh", "1667", "2008/12/13", "$103,600"],
    ["Jena Gaines", "Office Manager", "London", "3814", "2008/12/19", "$90,560"],
    ["Quinn Flynn", "Support Lead", "Edinburgh", "9497", "2013/03/03", "$342,000"],
    ["Charde Marshall", "Regional Director", "San Francisco", "6741", "2008/10/16", "$470,600"],
    ["Haley Kennedy", "Senior Marketing Designer", "London", "3597", "2012/12/18", "$313,500"],
    ["Tatyana Fitzpatrick", "Regional Director", "London", "1965", "2010/03/17", "$385,750"],
    ["Michael Silva", "Marketing Designer", "London", "1581", "2012/11/27", "$198,500"],
    ["Paul Byrd", "Chief Financial Officer (CFO)", "New York", "3059", "2010/06/09", "$725,000"],
    ["Gloria Little", "Systems Administrator", "New York", "1721", "2009/04/10", "$237,500"],
    ["Bradley Greer", "Software Engineer", "London", "2558", "2012/10/13", "$132,000"],
    ["Dai Rios", "Personnel Lead", "Edinburgh", "2290", "2012/09/26", "$217,500"],
    ["Jenette Caldwell", "Development Lead", "New York", "1937", "2011/09/03", "$345,000"],
    ["Yuri Berry", "Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)", "New York", "6154", "2009/06/25", "$675,000"],
    ["Caesar Vance", "Pre-Sales Support", "New York", "8330", "2011/12/12", "$106,450"],
    ["Doris Wilder", "Sales Assistant", "Sidney", "3023", "2010/09/20", "$85,600"],
    ["Angelica Ramos", "Chief Executive Officer (CEO)", "London", "5797", "2009/10/09", "$1,200,000"],
    ["Gavin Joyce", "Developer", "Edinburgh", "8822", "2010/12/22", "$92,575"],
    ["Jennifer Chang", "Regional Director", "Singapore", "9239", "2010/11/14", "$357,650"],
    ["Brenden Wagner", "Software Engineer", "San Francisco", "1314", "2011/06/07", "$206,850"],
    ["Fiona Green", "Chief Operating Officer (COO)", "San Francisco", "2947", "2010/03/11", "$850,000"],
    ["Shou Itou", "Regional Marketing", "Tokyo", "8899", "2011/08/14", "$163,000"],
    ["Michelle House", "Integration Specialist", "Sidney", "2769", "2011/06/02", "$95,400"],
    ["Suki Burks", "Developer", "London", "6832", "2009/10/22", "$114,500"],
    ["Prescott Bartlett", "Technical Author", "London", "3606", "2011/05/07", "$145,000"],
    ["Gavin Cortez", "Team Leader", "San Francisco", "2860", "2008/10/26", "$235,500"],
    ["Martena Mccray", "Post-Sales support", "Edinburgh", "8240", "2011/03/09", "$324,050"],
    ["Unity Butler", "Marketing Designer", "San Francisco", "5384", "2009/12/09", "$85,675"]
  ];

  var columnDefs = [{
    title: "Name"
  }, {
    title: "Position"
  }, {
    title: "Office"
  }, {
    title: "Extn."
  }, {
    title: "Start date"
  }, {
    title: "Salary"
  }];

  var myTable;

  myTable = $('#example').DataTable({
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    data: dataSet,
    columns: columnDefs,
     "scrollY": 200,
     "scrollX": true
  });


});
```

```css
.dataTable{}
.dataTable td,.dataTable th{border:1px solid #eee}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.1/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<div class="container">
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="dataTable table table-striped" id="example">

  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for something like this?

```js
var $table = $('table.scroll'),
$bodyCells = $table.find('tbody tr:first').children(),
colWidth;

//Adjust the width of thead cells when window resizes
$(window).resize(function() {
// Get the tbody columns width array
colWidth = $bodyCells.map(function() {
    return $(this).width();
}).get();

// Set the width of thead columns
$table.find('thead tr').children().each(function(i, v) {
    $(v).width(colWidth[i]);
});    
}).resize(); // Trigger resize handler
```

```css
body{
overflow:hidden;
}
wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
body {
    background-color:#a6e2ff;
}
.scroll table{
    margin: 5% auto auto auto;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: inherit;
    border-spacing: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: 2px solid #B7B7B7;
}
.scroll tbody tr:hover {
    background-color: #CECECE;
}
.scroll  td:hover {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
.scroll thead {
    background: #335599;background:linear-gradient(to bottom left,#335599,#335599);
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
 height:auto;
}
.scroll td, .scroll th {
    border: 1px solid #B7B7B7;
}
.scroll tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #f2f2f2}
.scroll td{
    padding: 8px;
}
.scroll th{
    padding: 8px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
display: none;
}
table.scroll tbody,table.scroll thead {
    display: block;
}
thead tr th { 
    height: 30px;
    line-height: auto;
}
table.scroll tbody {
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper scroll">
<table class="scroll">
    <thead><tr><th colspan="5" style="width: 240mm;">Head 2</th></tr></thead>
    <thead><tr><th style="width: 100mm;">Head 1</th><th style="width: 50mm;">Head 2</th><th style="width: 30mm;">Head 3</th><th style="width: 30mm;">Head 4</th><th style="width: 30mm;">Head 5</th></tr></thead>
    <thead><tr><th style="width: 100mm;">Head 1</th><th style="width: 50mm;">Head 2</th><th style="width: 30mm;">Head 3</th><th style="width: 30mm;">Head 4</th><th style="width: 30mm;">Head 5</th></tr></thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td style="width: 100mm;">Content 1</td><td style="width: 50mm;">Content 2</td><td style="width: 30mm;">Content 3</td><td style="width: 30mm;">Content 4</td><td style="width: 30mm;">Content 5</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Content 1</td><td>Content 2</td><td>Content 3</td><td>Content 4</td><td>Content 5</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Content 1</td><td>Content 2</td><td>Content 3</td><td>Content 4</td><td>Content 5</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Content 1</td><td>Content 2</td><td>Content 3</td><td>Content 4</td><td>Content 5</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Content 1</td><td>Content 2</td><td>Content 3</td><td>Content 4</td><td>Content 5</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Content 1</td><td>Content 2</td><td>Content 3</td><td>Content 4</td><td>Content 5</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Content 1</td><td>Content 2</td><td>Content 3</td><td>Content 4</td><td>Content 5</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Content 1</td><td>Content 2</td><td>Content 3</td><td>Content 4</td><td>Content 5</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Content 1</td><td>Content 2</td><td>Content 3</td><td>Content 4</td><td>Content 5</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Content 1</td><td>Content 2</td><td>Content 3</td><td>Content 4</td><td>Content 5</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Content 1</td><td>Content 2</td><td>Content 3</td><td>Content 4</td><td>Content 5</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Content 1</td><td>Content 2</td><td>Content 3</td><td>Content 4</td><td>Content 5</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Content 1</td><td>Content 2</td><td>Content 3</td><td>Content 4</td><td>Content 5</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Content 1</td><td>Content 2</td><td>Content 3</td><td>Content 4</td><td>Content 5</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Content 1</td><td>Content 2</td><td>Content 3</td><td>Content 4</td><td>Content 5</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table></div>
```